# pdfbox haw to working with Wingdings-Regular-Font font

Tags: java, pdfbox

Actually I'm using pdfbox 3.0.0-alpha3 to manepulat pdf documents,but whene i use this code to add checkbox and radiobox using the font Wingdings-Regular-Font :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      try(PDDocument document = new PDDocument()){


     PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
     document.addPage(page);


     File fontFile = new File("Wingdings-Regular-Font.ttf");
     PDType0Font font = PDType0Font.load(document, fontFile);


     PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

       // chekbox
       contentStream.beginText();
       contentStream.setFont(font, 16);
       contentStream.newLineAtOffset(100, 700);
       contentStream.showText("\u2610");
       contentStream.endText();

       //radio
       contentStream.beginText();
       contentStream.setFont(font, 16);
       contentStream.newLineAtOffset(100, 650);
       contentStream.showText("\u25CF");
       contentStream.endText();


       contentStream.close();


       document.save("output.pdf");
     }
   }
```

I have this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No glyph for U+2610 (?) in font Wingdings-Regular
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2.encode(PDCIDFontType2.java:381)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.encode(PDType0Font.java:476)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.encode(PDFont.java:337)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDAbstractContentStream.showTextInternal(PDAbstractContentStream.java:306)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDAbstractContentStream.showText(PDAbstractContentStream.java:260)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.showText(PDPageContentStream.java:37)
    at com.example.PdfSigningExample.main(PdfSigningExample.java:36)
```

I want to use the Wingdings-Regular-Font font to draw a chekbox or radiobox.

Comment: here are the unicode values, 0x2610 isn't mentioned http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html

Comment: thank you , but with U+002A i have this exception  : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No glyph for U+002A (*) in font Wingdings-Regular

Comment: I think what you need is U+25A1

Comment: i have the same exception :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No glyph for U+002A (*) in font Wingdings-Regular

Comment: ok I had a look at the font itself with DTL OTMaster. Try f0a8 and f06c, these worked.

Comment: Thank you, it's working well now. Can you please tell me how to find the correct code for a symbol ?

Comment: download DTL OTMaster 3.7 light. Maybe it's also possible with FontForge, but their GUI sucks. Or enter "show unicode from ttf file" into google.

Comment: thank you  
Tilman Hausherr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to DTL OTMaster 3.7 light, the correct characters turn out to be u+f0a8 and u+f06c. It might also be possible to get the same information with FontForge.

[image]

[image]